# How do I write a function for Varied amount input data for Python?

Tags: python

I'm having some problems with my code for the below assignment. It's not calculating the average value or the max value. The output I get with the below code is '0,0'. Could someone help me with this, please?

"6.12 LAB: Varied amount of input data
Statistics are often calculated with varying amounts of input data. Write a program that takes any number of integers as input, and outputs the average and max."

Example: If the input is: `15 20 0 5`, then the output should be: `10 20`

```
user_input = input()
tokens = user_input.split()
input_data = []
    
for token in tokens:
    token = int()
    input_data.append(token)
        
average = int(sum(input_data) /len(input_data))
max_num = max(input_data)
    
print(average, max_num)
```

Comment: When you do `token = int()`, you're basically doing `token = 0`. You probably meant to do `token = int(token)`.

Answer (score 2):

You meant to write `int(token)` instead of just `int()`. You can clean your code up a little bit by using "list comprehension" to place most of your code in one line like:

```
user_input = input()
tokens = [int(x) for x in user_input.split()]

# or even clean it more with: tokens = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
    
average = int(sum(tokens) /len(tokens))
max_num = max(tokens)

print(average, max_num)
```

With user input being `15 20 0 5` the output is `10 20`

Answer (score 1):

You were not converting `token` to an `int` value correctly. This is the correct syntax:

```
user_input = input()
tokens = user_input.split()
input_data = []

for token in tokens:
    token = int(token)
    input_data.append(token)
    
average = int(sum(input_data) /len(input_data))
max_num = max(input_data)

print(average, max_num)
```